# Unable to Configure LDAP in Gerrit

Tags: linux, ldap, gerrit

I was using Gerrit for quite some time, and I was using LDAP for login. At that time, the username didn't contain any special characters like '.'. But, as the policy changed, the new usernames contained '.' in them. Now, the new users are unable to login to Gerrit. The Gerrit configuration file is:

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        canonicalWebUrl = http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/
[database]
        type = mysql
        hostname = localhost
        database = reviewdb
        username = root
[index]
        type = LUCENE
[auth]
        type = LDAP_BIND
[ldap]
        server = ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        accountPattern = (sAMAccountName=${username})
        accountBase = OU=XXXX USERS,DC=xxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxx
        accountScope = sub
        referral = follow
        accountEmailAddress = ${username}@xxxxxx.com
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = smtprelay.xxxxx.com
        smtpServerPort = 25
[container]
        user = root
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = http://*:8080/
[cache]
        directory = cache
```

Error log:

```
[2016-02-11 18:08:56,560] INFO  com.google.gerrit.httpd.auth.ldap.LdapLoginServlet : 'xxx.xxxx' failed to sign in: Incorrect username or password
```

**I was using the correct username and password**. Is there any additional configurations that need to be added?

Gerrit Version: Gerrit Code Review (2.9.1)
Host machine: Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Off-topic. **Super User** or **Serverfault** maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I have configured my gerrit int this way I think you need change auth type  LDAP_BIND to LDAP

```
[auth]

             type = LDAP    

[LDAP]
         server = ldap://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX
         username = CN=XXX,CN=Users,DC=XXX,DC=local
         password = XXXXX
         accountBase = DC=XXX,DC=local
         accountScope = subtree
         accountPattern = (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=${username}))
         groupBase = DC=XXX,DC=local
         accountFullName = displayName
         sslVerify = false
         referral = follow
```